# ASP.NET Core CORS combining policies; enablecors in controller vs midleware configuration

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, cors

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core project and I want to enable CORS in my application. I have started with the ASP.NET Core [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#enable-cors-with-attributes) and I'm confused why we cannot combine the two methods as we can read below:

> You can apply different policies to controller/page-model/action with the `[EnableCors]` attribute. When the `[EnableCors]` attribute is applied to a controllers/page-model/action method, and CORS is enabled in middleware, both policies are applied. We recommend against combining policies. Use the `[EnableCors]` attribute or middleware, not both in the same app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to?
The result is: CORS is enabled or its not (for one resource).

You can either do this by using the Attribute-Syntax (`[EnableCors]`) on your controller / your action-method, or make use of the fluent-api-design like in example with

```
services.AddCors(options => options...);
```

But you still enable or do not enable the CORS for the specified resource, in one or the other way.
Which one you choose does not matter and depends on your application.

Microsofts recommendation against both approaches at once is because this is redundant and maybe will lead into confusion.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why we cannot do, knowing the issues helps avoid them. but in the documentation i cannot find further explanation about the issues when combining both way.

Comment: It is not an issue. The docu says "We recommend against combining". Its an recommendation to avoid confusion, because this would be an redundant defining of exactly the same functionality.

Comment: How the AspNetCore behave when enabling CORS in the startup.cs and using enablecors but not on all my controller/action ?

Comment: if it is enabled, its enabled. that means, if your startup enables CORS it will not get disabled by NOT using the attribute.

Comment: @cyptus but then how to use different policy on particular controller/method?

Comment: @krypru just pass the policy name to EnableCors attribute on the controller/method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware